# Then QFiledialog without 'DontUseNativeDialog' occurs messy code

Tags: qt, unicode, internationalization, codec

I build a QT project on CentOS 7.I have changed the /etc/locale.conf to 'zh_CN.gb2312'.

when I open QFiledialog  without 'DontUseNativeDialog' to chose a file , the file name displays in the dialog occurs messy code, even I add these following code in the main():

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB2312"));  
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB2312"));  
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB2312"));
```

How to fix this problem ?
My app will not only support English or Chinese , It should compatible with all the languages within the linux . The QT must can check the system language automatically, but how to ?

Thanks .

Comment: Could you specify _messy_? Maybe include a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the secret :
 when I was in the UTF-8 environment， and name a file , the file name is stored in utf-8 style . when I change to CGB2312 environment，the utf-8 is interpret in GB2312 by glibc , so the messy code emerge. The messy code Not noly in QT QFiledialog, but so in the bshell . The QT native GUI window and the bshell both base on glibc ,right ?

May be the gnome treat this specially , it is smart enough to interpret the encoding of the file name , so in gnome file browse toolkit, the name shows right under both the UTF-8 and GB2312 environment .